# How to check if a link has some text and evaluate a condition based upon the value of text- Jquery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to evaluate a condition based upon a link text and show hide a tab depending on what value it returns.

HTML:

```
<span class="links">
        <a href="#info">Info</a>
        <a href="#accounts>Accounts</a>
        <a href="#user">Users</a>
 </span>
```

Here im trying to check if the `'a'` has value 'Accounts', if so hide a div.

I tried this:

Js:

```
 var link = $('a').filter( function () {
   return $(this).text() =="Accounts";
    //will return: [<a href="#accounts>Accounts</a>]
 });
```

And in some place where the 'Accounts' link does not exists, it will return: `[]`

Now Im not sure how to check for a condition whether the array is empty or has a value:

```
 if (link is empty){
     //hide ` <a href="#accounts>Accounts</a>`
 }else{
      //show ` <a href="#accounts>Accounts</a>`
  }
```

Any ideas how this condition can be evaluated?/
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `:contains` selector. And since 0 is a *falsy* value, you can directly compare.

```
if ($("a:contains('Accounts')").length) {
    $("#accounts").hide();
} else {
    $("#accounts").show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
var link = $('a').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() == "Accounts";
    //will return: [<a href="#accounts>Accounts</a>]
});
//link is  a jQuery object that has a length property that tells how many dom elements are referred by this jQuery object
if (link.length) {
    //show div as 
} else {
    //hide div
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just incase you might have a link with text Accounts in the future in some other part of your page, I would do this:

```
<span class="links" id="mylinks">
    <a href="#info">Info</a>
    <a href="#accounts>Accounts</a>
    <a href="#user">Users</a>
</span>

var link = $('#mylinks').find(a).filter(function () {
   return $(this).text() == "Accounts";

});

if (link.length) {
    //show div 
} else {
    //hide div
}
```

Comment: great! that worked!! now instead of show-hide div, I'm trying to show-hide the <a> 'Accounts'</a> text, can you help me with that? Thanks

Comment: @user1234 You mean you want to hide the Accounts link? Then on what condition?

Comment: if (link.length === 0){//hide the Accounts link}else{//show Accounts link}

Comment: So if the link exists you want to hide it? I guess you can just use `link.hide()` , can you try?